# How to identify javascript functions using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have JS code.

I would like to find where each function starts (via the '{' sign)
How can I find it using regex?

**EDIT:** I understand that it's impossible to be 100% accurte, how can I find 99% of the functions via regex?
Are there any quick alternatives?

Comment: You shouldn't parse Javascript code with regex, as Javascript is not a regular language and a `{` symbol can mean different things in different contexts.

Comment: There is the `function name (/*complicated stuff*/){` and the `function (/*complicated stuff*/){` syntax. match those, get their location, and be happy in the easy cases.

Comment: @Nish, `var whoops = "function FOO";`

Comment: People like you are the reason why we have this security and hacking problem.  Language class mismatches while parsing lead to enumerable invisible regions in the parse "tree", cutting both ways (invisible for the JS interpreter or for your "parser").  In there, you can hide all sorts of stuff.  Carefully constructed Hidden Stuff(TM) will explode on you, smash your stack, steal you wife and (maybe) root your box.  But please, continue!  ;-)

Comment: @nobody, *hackers* are the reason we have security and hacking problems. Don't blame the victim. That being said, it's important to teach people so that they don't become victims.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is not a regular language, and cannot be parsed using a regular expression. You will need to use Plain Old Code™ if you want to accurately parse JavaScript.

For example, this snippet creates a function:

```
function()
{
    alert('foo');
}
```

Whereas this snippet calls a function and a code block:

```
foo.
function()
{
    alert('foo');
}
```

These sorts of nuances are impossible to pick up with a simple regular expression.

Comment: Anyone care to comment which part of this answer is ["egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect"](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down)

Answer (score 0):

If you make it into a string you can use this solution.
I had a similar problem and I did this function to find the functions:

```
// String with some functions to search.
var myStr =
`
foo1(){
   var blabla = null;
}

foo2 () {
   var blabla = null;
}

foo3(params) {
   var blabla = null;
}

foo4(params1,params2) {
   var blabla = null;
}

foo5(params1: string, params2: int) {
   var blabla = null;
}
`;

// Function to find functions syntax.
function searchForFunctions(str) {
   var positionStartFunctions = [];
   var functionArr = str.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\s*\({1}([a-z0-9,:\s]*)\){1}\s*\{/g);

   for(var i=0; i<functionArr.length; i++) {
      var functionLength = functionArr[i].length;
      var functionIndexMatched = str.indexOf(functionArr[i]);
      var positionOfCurlyBracket = (functionLength + functionIndexMatched);

      positionStartFunctions.push(positionOfCurlyBracket);
   }

   return positionStartFunctions;
}

var listOfCurlyBracketsFunctions = searchForFunctions(myStr);
console.log(listOfCurlyBracketsFunctions);
```

The function returns an array with the index of the first curly bracket on each function found.

I made this regex to matches with every function structure with params or with space between `)` and `{`.

It's been a long time but maybe this will help someone else.

Comment: Thank you for including an explanation alongside your code.